# How can I limit the user when he/she picking time via using showTimePicker?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a date/time picker function in **flutter**. First, the user picks start time, then end time. However, the user can pick the first end time, then the start time. But the thing is I want to limit the user when he/she picks the times.

**for example
If the user picks the start time as 1:00 pm, he/she cannot pick 12:59 pm. It must be at least 1:01 pm. When the user picks 12:59 pm the showTimePicker widget shows up again and it works until the user picks something after 1:00 pm.**

I did something but It looks complicated (do while) and I guess I can make it more simple with your advice.
Let me share the code with you.

```
              do {
                      time = await showTimePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                          return MediaQuery(
                            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
                            child: child!,
                          );
                        },
                      );
                      eventEndDate = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.minute);
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("You cannot pick any date before the start time!")));
                     
                    } while (((time.hour * 60 + time.minute) <= (eventStartDate!.hour * 60 + eventStartDate!.minute)) &&
                        (eventEndDate!.day == eventStartDate!.day && eventEndDate!.month == eventStartDate!.month));
```

I hope that I can explain it well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need to do is to store the times in separate variables and calculate both date time pickers' limits when the state changes.